# With NSSavePanel, how can the user choose a specific file type to save?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssavepanel

I am writing an application in Cocoa which allows the user to export data in 3 different formats: CSV, JSON, and XML. I have added the allowed extensions to an NSSavePanel:

```
NSSavePanel* saveFile = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
NSArray* extensions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"csv", @"json" @"xml", nil];
[saveFile setAllowedFileTypes:extensions];
```

However, how can I set up the NSSavePanel to allow the user to select which format to save in, such as in TextEdit where a "File format" list box is offered? If this is possible, how would I then determine which format had been selected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a user-defined `NSView` to the `NSSavePanel` using `setAccessoryView:`, see Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSavePanel/setAccessoryView%3a). There is also an Apple sample [Custom Save](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CustomSave/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004201). You add your format selection controls to this accessory view.